# WPF- Changing Tooltip background to Transparent

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I am attempting to make it so that when I hover over a button in my application, the "tooltip" displays my wording, along with a transparent background, instead of the white background.

I am merely trying to change the tooltip default settings to a transparent background..

I have looked and looked, but to no success.. anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

Place this in the resource dictionary of your view, or for your application.

Comment: This corrrectly change it, but still the tooltip have a gray border, how i can change it?

Comment: Change the Border property ala above.

Answer (score 5):

And this is the final style which sets the tooltip background to transparent:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

Note that you need to set also the BorderBrush to Transparent, not only the Background.

Comment: This is incorrect, tested and setting the background to transparent only works fine.

Comment: @NewBee I have to disagree. When not setting the borderbrush to transparent, a gray border will be visible. Tested with .Net 4.5.2 - on which version did you test it? Somtimes, controls change. Or it has to do with the selected OS theme.

Answer (score 2):

The class `ToolTip` has property `Background`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.controls.tooltip_members.aspx. You can set `Background` to `Transparent`.

Comment: Gotcha.. I just realized my simple mistake.. I just needed to set the <Tooltip Background="Transparent"> Thanks!