# Backgroundcolor of entire ToolTip

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background, tooltip

Does anyone know a simple XAML solution to change the entire background of a `ToolTip`?

I did the following:

```
<Image Height="16" Source="Images/Icons/Add2.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="16" Opacity="0.99" Grid.Column="0">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <Grid Background="#000000">
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <TextBlock Text="Header1" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0"/>
             <TextBlock Text="Subitem" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="1"/>
         </Grid>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

But the result looks like that:

[image: Tooltip background color]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. You set the background to black (#000000 = Black) and it is black...

Comment: Yes of course, but around the black area there is a grey section left.
For me it looks like: Full GraySection -> Smaller BlackArea in the GraySection

Comment: What @Tim said and also it looks like you want a [StackPanel](http://wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html)

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying. I couldn't tell from the size of the screenshot that the gray was part of the tooltip and not just something else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that all you're really doing is setting the CONTENT of the tooltip, not the tooltip itself.

So you'll need to style the tooltip to make this happen. There are some ways to do it with resources as seen in this post:

[WPF- Changing Tooltip background to Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314856/wpf-changing-tooltip-background-to-transparent)

or you can change your code to wrap that grid with an explicit ToolTip and set its background property:

```
<Image.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Background="Black">
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </ToolTip>
</Image.ToolTip>
```

Comment: Ok. I've already thought about that. Then I've to do it that way. (I will accept it as the answer in a minute...) Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 1):

To set the tooltip background you can override the style of the tooltip for the parent control. Below is your code with added style.

```
<Image Height="16" Source="Images/Icons/Add2.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="16" Opacity="0.99" Grid.Column="0">
    <Image.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#000000" />
        </Style>
    </Image.Resources>
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <Grid>
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <TextBlock Text="Header1" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0"/>
             <TextBlock Text="Subitem" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="1"/>
         </Grid>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, simple and to the point!

Answer (score 0):

**To change or Set the Background/Foreground color for the Tooltip in DataGrid in WPF**

1. Create the DataGrid as "Grid1" and add the DataGridTextColumn which contains the ToolTip with item.
2. To change the Background colour for the ToolTip, add the Setter property in the DataGrid Resources

```
     <DataGrid x:Name="Grid1">
                 <DataGrid.Resources>
                   <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                   </Style>
                 </DataGrid.Resources>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="ActionName" Binding={Binding ActionName}>
               <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                 <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip">
                   <Setter.Value>
                   <UniformGrid Columns="1">
                   <TextBlock Text="Action List" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="Cut"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="Copy"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="Delete"/>
                   </UniformGrid>
                  </Setter.Value>                                                
                 </Setter>             
               </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
         </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding some code does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.

Comment: Try this.It will be helpfull